# How to know that a particular element is present or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to know that a particular input type is present or not in a `div`?

If I use

```
$("#inputId").val()
```

And there is no element present on this, then js gives an error.

So how could I know that the input element named `inputId` is present or not?

Reply me ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if

```
$('#inputId').length > 0
```

i.e. if the current selector matched any elements.

But if `$('#inputId').length == 0` then `$('#inputId').val()` will be `undefined`. This is different from the scenario where the input exists, because `val()` would always yield a string, that is or isn't null.

Now, you would produce an *error* only if you're trying to do stuff with the value, that may or may not be `undefined`. For instance, the following would not work if `#inputId` does not exist in the DOM:

```
if($('#inputId').val().length > 0) { ... }
```

... since you'd be trying to access `undefined.length`. However, you could still do

```
if(!!$('#inputId').val()) {
    // this code will only be executed if #inputId exists, and has a value that
    // is not an empty string
}
```

If you're writing form validation, it might be more useful to do

```
if($('#inputId').val() !== '') {
    // this code will be executed if #inputId has a value, or if it does not
    // exist in the DOM at all
}
```

The former condition checks that the result of `.val()` resolves to true, which is not the case for an empty string or for undefined. (It is also not the case for `null`, `NaN`, `false` or `0`, but `.val()` will never yield any of those results)

The latter checks that the result of `.val()` is not exactly an empty string, which is true for an actual value, as well as for `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks Davis. This is very helpful. i think it will work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property, which will tell you the number of elements in the current selector.

```
if ($("#inputId").length > 0) 
{
    // code that depends on inputId being present can go in here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($("#inputId").length)  { }
```

No need to be verbose, checking whether length === 0 or greater than 0: length value itself is automatically casted as a boolean inside an if statement

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery:

```
var input = document.getElementById('inputId');
if (input) {
  // the input exists
  alert(input.value);
} else {
  // the input doesn't exist
  alert('Ooops! An input with id "inputId" doesn\'t exist.');
}
```